# Vue.js 2: Conditional Rendering not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm having problems with [Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Composing-with-Components), in that not one single example is working.

Here's the Vue code:

```
Vue.component('sub-folder', {
    props: ['folder'],
    template: '#template-folder-item'
});

var buildFoldersList = new Vue({
    el: '#sub-folders',
    data: {
        foldersList: this.foldersList,
        foldersStatus: this.foldersStatus
    },
    created () {
        this.buildFolders()
    },
    methods: {
        buildFolders: function () {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'api/folder/get_subfolders/' + browser_folder_id,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    "folder_id": browser_folder_id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Data"); console.log(data.result);
                    self.foldersList = data.result;
                    self.foldersStatus = ( data.result.length > 0 ) ? true : false;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    self.foldersStatus = false;
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
```

Here are the examples of HTML code that don't work:

```
            <div v-if="foldersStatus == true" class="list-group" id="sub-folders">
                <sub-folder v-for="folder in foldersList" :key="folder.folder_id" v-bind:folder="folder"></sub-folder>
            </div>
            <div v-else-if="foldersStatus == false" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <strong>Hello!</strong> You don't have any Folders in here!
            </div>
```

... and:

```
            <div v-if="foldersStatus == true" class="list-group" id="sub-folders">
                <sub-folder v-for="folder in foldersList" :key="folder.folder_id" v-bind:folder="folder"></sub-folder>
            </div>
            <div v-if="foldersStatus == false" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <strong>Hello!</strong> You don't have any Folders in here!
            </div>
```

... and:

```
            <div v-if="foldersStatus" class="list-group" id="sub-folders">
                <sub-folder v-for="folder in foldersList" :key="folder.folder_id" v-bind:folder="folder"></sub-folder>
            </div>
            <template v-else>
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <strong>Hello!</strong> You don't have any Folders in here!
            </div>
            </template>
```

I've checked, and `foldersStatus` is correct, so I'm missing something.

**Update**

I've found something strange which makes no sense to me:

```
            <div v-if="1 == 2" class="list-group" id="sub-folders">
                <sub-folder v-for="folder in foldersList" :key="folder.folder_id" v-bind:folder="folder"></sub-folder>
            </div>
            <div v-if="1 == 2" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <strong>Hello!</strong> You don't have any Folders in here!
            </div>
```

Here, the first `div` is hidden while the second remains visible. So whatever is happening is overthrowing whatever behaviour the code is attempting to produce.

Comment: 'Not one single example is working' > care to provide the specifics of how your output differs from what you expect?

Comment: Bootstrap alert either appears regardless of whether there are folders, or not at all.

Comment: I think the problem is that the Bootstrap alert is _outside_ of the `sub-folders` element and therefore not controllable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated after data template was provided:

https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/13/

....

You have a strange code in `data` section:

```
 data: {
        foldersList: this.foldersList,
        foldersStatus: this.foldersStatus
    },
```

It's not how it's used. You'd better initialize it in some way rather than self-linking it to itself. It makes no sense.

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/10/

It works fine. You can toggle switch by clicking a button.

I guess you should look at console errors output. My guess is there's missing closing curly brace somewhere.

Comment: Hi, there were no errors in the console. However, since refactoring the code to match your suggestion, I'm getting multiple errors: `[Vue warn]: Property or method "folder" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in <Root>)` and: `[Vue warn]: Error in render function: 
(found in <Root>)` and: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: It's worth noting that I kept the original `template` value: `template: '#template-folder-item'`.

Comment: @WayneSmallman there's an error in your template 'template-folder-item' probably. Why don't you show it. `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined` - well, sure! There's no such properties defined inside `folderList` in my fiddle.

Comment: I'm using the template because when I use the embedded version, I get errors with values in the attributes (I've tried both `v-bind` and custom filters, but neither worked). Also, if you look at the template, it's too much to embed in the code.

Comment: @WayneSmallman Sometimes it really helps if you can actually provide a working example to demonstrate an issue: which you have not done both in your original question and the refactored code after taking into account wostex's suggestions. It is extremely difficult to troubleshoot issues when we do not actually know what you've implemented precisely.

Comment: @Terry, what's happening isn't so much the code I've written but how Vue works, which I don't understand enough _to_ replicate.

Comment: @WayneSmallman It's up to you to decide what you want, but if you aren't getting a workable solution from the community even after a day it probably speaks volume of the quality and information available in your original question... or rather, the lack thereof. Providing an MCVE does no harm.

Comment: @Terry, the code relies on data from an external source that cannot be replicated, which is then used to set the values of several variables. At this point, I'm at the limits of what I understand. Here's a re-working of the code that doesn't work because I — as explained — I don't know how replicate it work ( https://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/ve2fwazu/11/ ).

Comment: @WayneSmallman Have you looked at the asynchronous requests made available by JSFiddle? They have examples on the sidebar where you can use their API to generate fake AJAX responses.

Comment: Look: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/13/ Is that what you need? 'Clear list' to make it empty, "Load list" to pretend loading in 1s.

Comment: @wostex, I wouldn't have figured that out for myself, so thank you! Also, I get a practical introduction to computed properties, too.

Comment: @Terry, I did have a look, but the data source itself is hidden behind OAuth.

Comment: @WayneSmallman please mark the answer as correct if it answers you question.